# Substring interpolation

Tags: c#, string, string-interpolation

Is it possible to do a string interpolation formatting a substring of a string?

I have been searching the Microsoft documents about string interpolation but cannot get a working sample done. [reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/composite-formatting#format-string-component).

Currently I have :

```
var description = "the quick brown fox";
var result = $"{description.Substring(0, description.Length < 10 ? description.Length : 10)} jumps..",
```

using string interpolation I would ideally like to use:

```
var description = "the quick brown fox";
var result = $"{description:10} jumps..",
```

**editted**

I would expect the output of result to be :

```
The quick  jumps..
```

Comment: What happens when you use this code? What output do you expect?

Comment: @pcreyght - What is your expected output?

Comment: It should be `{description,10}` (comma, not colon) to get the string to align. Even then, you can't use alignment to cut off the string -- oversized values will spill. This is true for `String.Format` as it is for interpolation. If you're doing this often, an (`internal`) extension method on `String` for the substring logic would come in handy.

Comment: @JonSkeet My output is "The quick brown fox jumps.." . It does not take the substring of 10 of the original [description] variable. sorry for the faulty comma !

Comment: Ah, I'd misread the question somehow. (I was trying the *working* code rather than your "ideal" code.) No, you can't use `description:10` like that. If you want a substring, you need to call Substring.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the question was:
"Is it possible to do a string interpolation formatting a substring of a string?"
In such a manner:

```
var result = $"{description:10} jumps..",
```

The answer given from @JohnSkeet and @JeroenMostert was most acurate:
"No, it is not possible."

There are various ways to simplify the call. thanks for @PiotrWojsa for pointing that out.   however that doesnt involve the interpolation part..

Answer (score 4):

You can use [ranges](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/proposals/csharp-8.0/ranges) (C# 8):

```
var description = "the quick brown fox";
var result = $"{description[..10]} jumps..";
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use **Take** method:

```
description.Take(10)
```

Unfortunately, this method returns IEnumerable which cannot be directly converted to string (ToString method would return name of type as usually when using it on IEnumerable).
You can't create string using it, because string constructor requires array of chars, so the easiest solution will be:

```
new string(description.Take(10).ToArray())
```

Still, such code makes it harder to read if you want to use it few times, so you can create extension method:

```
public static string TakeFirst(this string text, int number)
{
    if (text == null)
        return null;

    return new string(text.Take(number).ToArray());
}
```

Then you can just use it:

```
$"{description.TakeFirst(10)} jumps..";
```

EDIT: As mentioned in comments, because of allocation of array each time this method is called, there might occur serious performance issues. You can avoid them by implementing TakeFirst method using **Substring** instead of **Take(x).ToArray()** solution.

Comment: Of all the ways to format a string to have only N characters initially, this is absolutely the least efficient, resulting in multiple allocations. While premature optimization is the root of all evil and all that, this one is bad enough that it could have serious impact if it unwittingly trickled through your code base with large values for `number` (and shoved into loops). Don't do this and take the `Substring` route.

Comment: I'm still upvoting it because it shows the principle that solves the OP's problem.

Comment: `string.Concat(description.Take(10))` instead of `new string(description.Take(10).ToArray())`